# How to eliminate angle in a Glissette equation of carried point of a line sliding along two lines not at right angles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, gm.general-mathematics, trigonometric-functions

Glissettes are the curves trances out by a point carried by a curve, which is made to slide between given points or curves. My problem specifically include a line which slides between two fixed lines (which are not necessary at right angles), and a carried point in the line (no necessary at the center).

I found some text in [Notes on Roulettes and Glissettes : William Henry Besant](https://archive.org/details/notesonroulette00besagoog/page/n65) (pages 51-52), which solve this for two lines at right angles, and add a note how to do it for two lines which are not at right angles, but doesn't solve it completely.

For simplicity, assume one of the fixed lines is the x-axis, and it intersect the other fixed line at the origin, and the angle between them is $\alpha$. If the moving line has a length $d_1+d_2$, and the carried point as at distance $d_1,d_2$ from the line endpoints, the Glissette points satisfy the following for any angle $\theta$:

$ y = d_2 \cos (\theta + \alpha) ,\quad x = \frac{d_1 \cos \theta}{\sin \alpha} + \frac{y}{\tan \alpha} $

How do I eliminate the angle $\theta$ from the equation? The end curve is ellipse but I can't calculate it's exact equation. I would like to have an equation that depends only on $x,y$ without $\theta$, where $d_1,d_2,\alpha$ are known and constants, $f(x,y)=0$.

[See image for illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKI99.png)

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Please give bibliographic information for the "Notes on Roulettes and Glissettes" that you mention so that readers could find it easily.

Comment: Added a link, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

The equation $f(x, y)=0$ is as follows:
$\sin{\alpha}^{2}d_{2}^{2}.x^{2}-2 cos(\alpha)sin(\alpha)(d_{1}+d_{2})x y+\Big(d_{1}^{2}+d_{2}(2d_{1}+d_{2}) cos(\alpha)^{2}\Big) y^{2}-d_{1}^{2}d_{2}^{2} sin(\alpha)^{2}=0$